# Opção direta de Trecho de Código (snippet) com Bootstrap

Tags: novo-recurso

Pessoal já vi que tem uma pergunta bem similar a minha. Porém gostaria de levantar a questão de por que não tem o `Bootstrap` direto no Select Box do snippet.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou me justificar. Sou novo na comunidade e tenho visto bastante gente com dúvidas em BS. Acredito que pela falta dessa opção ocorrem muitos problemas na hora de perguntar e de responder também.

Apenas gostaria de sugerir que adotassem algo desse tipo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Acho que tendo a opção direta melhoraria muito a qualidade das perguntas/respostas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*OBS: Não consegui exportar o .gif sem ficar azulado...*

Comment: Interessante mas acho difícil de ser aceita, pode tentar propor no [**Metão**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Pode ver que as bibliotecas disponíveis ai não possuem dependência, por isso é simples colocá-las como opções no snippet. Já o Boostrap, além de incluir o CSS, ainda precisa validar que a ver versão do BS funcione com a versão correspondente do JQuery (PS: Note que não incluíram nem suporte a versão 3.x no select atual). Provavelmente será sugerido que use o botão "Adicionar biblioteca externa".

Comment: @Renan é eu tinha notado que são apenas bibliotecas sem dependências, por isso coloquei a opção de ativer o JS direto na parte de edição, até pq nem tudo do BS precisa de JS para funcionar. Assim que sobrar um tempo para traduzir vou ver se porto no "Metão" tb...